# play sound from raw folder proportional with each row of listview

Tags: android, listview, audio

I want in the following code play sound files in raw folder proportional with each row of list,its mean for example played 1.mp3 with lorem and played 2.mp3 with ipsum and...

what should i add in my code?

please help me...

my code:

```
    public class InflatList extends ListActivity {
private TextView selection;
private static final String[] items = {"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
    selection = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }

  //=====================
  //New Class Starts Here
  //=====================
  class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public IconicAdapter() {
        super(InflatList.this, R.layout.row, items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView label = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(items[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.pic);
            ImageButton btnplay = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);

        return(row);
    }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have done the sound playing early

So you can get following from the **onListItemClick**

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

             // find which item clicked from the id,

            //Place your code here for play video




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are number from 1.mp3, 2.mp3... for 1'st, 2'nd element... and so on
(if different use different logic to find the name of the file)

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
         String fname = String.value(position + 1);
         int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(fname, "raw", getPackageName());
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID);
         mediaPlayer.start();
}
```